# Grey lines in Layers panel

Tags: qgis-3

I noticed a change in the Layer Panel of QGIS 3.10/3.12. Vertical grey lines are found at the end of each layer's line. What are they? Do they serve any function? Or are they simply there to help identifying the limits of each layer's line from the right side of the panel?

[image]

Comment: could you add a screenshot to help us see what you mean?